# Regex: Match list of words without reusing previously matched words

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern that will match any string containing the words '28', 'bonus', and 'day'.

At the moment I have come up with this:

```
(bonus|(days|day)|(28th|28)|twenty[ \-\t]*(eighth|eight))[ \ta-z]*(bonus|days|day|(28th|28)|twenty[ \-\t]*(eighth|eight))[ \ta-z]*(bonus|days|day|(28th|28)|twenty[ \-\t]*(eighth|eight))
```

You can view the results here: https://regex101.com/r/oOcGqk/8

The trouble I am having is that any word can be used multiple times, and still be matched. For example: 'day day bonus', 'bonus bonus bonus'. How can I exclude strings that use any of these words ('28', 'bonus', 'day') more than once?

Comment: Your regex is very complex, are the rules you need to follow really that complicated (your first sentence suggests otherwise)? Could you describe what the rules for matching a string are exactly? Chances are this can be done more simply and without the duplication problem you're encountering.

Comment: @pietzcker The rules that the regex should follow are: 1) Match any string containing '28', 'bonus', and 'day' 2) Not match any string containing any of those word more than once. eg. 'day day bonus' or 'bonus bonus bonus'

Comment: Also: Which regex flavor? I hope it's not JavaScript, otherwise the solution I'm thinking of won't work...

Comment: @pietzcker I am not sure about the flavor. I am using the actionscript 3 RegExp object.

Comment: That's JavaScript's regex engine. Bummer.

Comment: @pietzcker At least I am aware of the engine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/oOcGqk/10) regex expresion is solution:

```
(?=.*bonus)(?=.*day)(?=.*28|twenty\s*-?\s*eight).*
```

Comment: This does not exclude multiple matches of the same word.

Comment: @TimPietzcker "any string containing '28', 'bonus', and 'day'" ... containing  != having exacly one

Comment: Please see the last sentence of the question: "How can I exclude strings that use any of these words ('28', 'bonus', 'day') more than once?"

Comment: @TimPietzcker please se how my answer works before auming i didn't read, the problem was that day day day and common was matched now it is not

Comment: Try it with `day bonus day 28`.

Comment: I think the question was asked this way because in colio's regex you coud have match in this case `day day day` and he wanted to prevent that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136392/discussion-between-maciej-kozieja-and-tim-pietzcker).

Comment: Yes, that was my fault for not realizing how my question was worded. I have not used regex beyond simple keyword matching, so I am not very aware of its many features. In this case 'day bonus day 28' is acceptable to match, I just wanted to be sure all three words existed together in a string. Both you and @Pietzcker answered my question, but   now that I realize what solution my problem requires, I am going to use your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a decent regex engine, you could make use of a nice trick:

```
^     # Start of string
(?=(?:(?!bonus).)*bonus()(?:(?!bonus).)*$) 
# Explanation: This lookahead assertion makes sure that "bonus" occurs exactly once 
# in the string. It doesn't actually match any text, it just "looks ahead" to see if 
# that condition is met. However, it contains an empty capturing group "()" that only 
# participates in the match if the lookahead assertion succeeds. We can check this later.
(?=(?:(?!days?).)*days?()(?:(?!days?).)*$)
(?=(?:(?!28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*(?:28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?)()(?:(?!28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*$)
[\w\s]*  # Match a string that only contains alnum character or whitespace
\1\2\3   # Assert that all three words participated in the match
$        # End of string.
```

You can test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/3Afe6s/1)

In JavaScript, you'll have to spell out all possible permutations. Unfortunately, JS doesn't even allow verbose regexes, so it's going to be monstrous.

Just as a starting point: The following regex will match strings that contain `bonus`, `days` and `28` exactly once, but it only allows them in the order "`bonus`, `days` and `28`"  or  "`days`,`bonus` and `28`". You'd need to add the other four permutations to get a complete regex (and a complete mess). Do this programmatically, not with a regex.

```
^(?:(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*bonus(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*days?(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*(?:28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?)(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*|(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*days?(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*bonus(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*(?:28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?)(?:(?!bonus|days?|28(?:th)?|twenty-eighth?).)*)$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/EwHN6a/1). You have been warned.

Comment: This is not a very scalable solution.